# RegEx: How to make greedy quantifier really really greddy (and never give back)?

Tags: regex

For example I have this RegEx:

```
([0-9]{1,4})([0-9])
```

[image]

Which gives me these matching groups when testing with string "3041":

[image]

As you can see, group2 is filled before group1 even if the quantifier is greedy.

How can I instead make sure to fill group1 before group2?

**EDIT1:** I want to have the same regEx, but have "3041" in group1 and group2 empty.

**EDIT2:** I want to have "3041" in group1 and group2 empty.  And, yes, I want the regEx to **not** match!,

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The `[0-9]` is an obligatory pattern. If you make the first one possessive, this whole pattern will never match any string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I want to have the same regEx, but have "3041" in capturing group 1 and capturing group 2 empty

Comment: Make the last one optional - `([0-9]{1,4})([0-9]?)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Sorry, let me think this over again, I have a very complex regex in front of me and I think I oversimplified it too much.

Comment: Ok, take your time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, I found what I want:  I want to have "3041" in group1 and group2 empty.  And, yes, I want the regEx to NOT match!,  I want only 5 digits strings to match the whole RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an input `"1234"`, the pattern: `([0-9]{1,4})([0-9])` **is** being as greedy as possible.

The first capture group *cannot* contain four characters, otherwise the last part of the pattern would not match.

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

```
([0-9]{1,4})([0-9]?)
```

By making the second group optionally empty, the first group can contain all four characters.

Edit:

> I want the regEx to **not** match!, I want only 5 digits strings to match the whole RegEx.

In this case, your pattern should not really be "1-4 characters" in the first group, since you *only* want to match a group of 4:

```
([0-9]{4})([0-9])
```

In some regex flavours (i.e. not all languages support this), it is also possible to make quantifiers [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) (although this is unnecessary in your case, as shown above). For example:

```
([0-9]{1,4}+)([0-9])
```

This will *force* the first group to match as far as it can (i.e. 4 characters), so a 3-character match does not get attempted and the overall pattern fails to match.

Edit2:

> Is "possessiveness" available in Javascript? If not, any workarounds?

Unfortunately, possessive quantifiers are not available in JavaScript.

However, you can emulate the behaviour (in a slightly ugly way) with a lookahead:

```
(?=([0-9]{1,4}))\1([0-9])
```

In general, a possessive quantifier `a++` can be emulated as: `(?=(a+))\1`.

Comment: I want to have "3041" in group1 and group2 empty.  And, yes, I want the regEx to NOT match!,  I want only 5 digits strings to match the whole RegEx.

Comment: @Emilio Please see my edit. I didn't realise you wanted the string to *not* match.

Comment: sorry, I over simplified again, I cannot know how many characters I want :/  The only thing I know is that I want a way to have a greedy quantifier that doesn't give back. Is it something possible?

Comment: thanks! (sorry I commented after you posted) Is "possessiveness" available in Javascript? If not, any workarounds?

Comment: (It would *really* help if you include all information in the original question, rather than drip-feeding it in comments...)

Comment: Sorry, I'll close this question and make a new one.

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Hopefully this actually solves your problem now?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands you only need anchors:

```
^([0-9]{4})([0-9])$
```

This will only match **five digits strings** and will fail on any other string.

Comment: :/  It's only a simplification of a complicated regEx I have. It's a small part of a longer regEx. It's not a regEx that stands by itself.

Comment: @Emilio: I'd suggest to not let us poke in the dark but to provide your realistic input strings and expected outputs.

Comment: Trust me you would've downvoted my question if I posted the real regEx I have here.  I'm doing my best here :)

Comment: [mcve] -- Your example **is** minimal and verifiable, but it's not *complete*.